# find a string in a sorted array of strings having some NULL strings as well

Tags: c, arrays, string

An array of string is given in sorted order but it can have any number of null strings in between. I need to search a string in that array of strings. If string found then return the index of that, otherwise return -1.

I have written the below code using strcmp() which works for array of string without NULL string only. How to extend it to work for arrays having Null strings as well.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>

int search(char *arr[], char *strtofind, int l, int r)
{
    int mid , val;
    if(l <= r)
    {
        mid = (l+r)/2;
        val = strcmp(strtofind, arr[mid]);
        if(val == 0)
            return mid;
        else if(val > 0)
        {
            return search(arr, strtofind,mid+1,r);
        }
        else
        {
            return search(arr, strtofind, l, mid-1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    int idx;
    //char *arr[] = {"STR1", "STR2","STR3","STR4","STR5","STR6","STR7"}; // WORKS HERE
    char *arr[] = {"STR1", "STR2","STR3",NULL,"STR4",NULL,"STR5"};  // NOT WORKS HERE

    idx = search(arr, "STR4", 0, 6);
    printf("Found at = %d\n", idx);

    printf("Will is Everything.");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: you hae to check if `arr[mid] != NULL` before you use `strcmp`

Comment: @esskar: ok then If it is null how should I proceed

Comment: `if (arr[0][mid] == NULL) return -1;`

Comment: If the pointer is `NULL`, then proceed with the search. Either of the two `else` cases could be used.

Comment: @Igor `arr[mid]` can't be NULL; its a true two-dim array of arrays.

Comment: since its sorted, are all the null pointers at the same place?

Comment: Binary search works on sorted data. if `arr[index]` is NULL then should we now search on left side or right side of the array? You can't decide how to proceed if there are NULLs at random locations in the array. So you have to use *linear* search.

Comment: If you find a null, at the midpoint, you must do a linear search both upward and downward to find the two non-nulls (or end of array) that bracket it.  Then pick one for the new value of `mid`. Use the other to eliminate the entire string of nulls from the search bracket during update.  In practice you'd never do this because the nulls destroy the O(log n) time bound of binary search.  You'd squeeze out all the nulls first so searches would be fast.

Comment: I must be seeing something different than everyone else. I still want to know how you're going to store a NULL **pointer** in that *array of **arrays***, each element of which is a `char[20]`. Were this a `char *arr[] = {...};` it would make sense. As-written, it makes none.

Comment: @WhozCraig OP probably means something like:`char arr[][20] = {"STR1", "", "STR2", "", "STR3", "", "STR4"};` i.e. empty strings rather than NULL pointers.

Comment: @KingsIndian Maybe so, but in that case I would have expected to see it in the posted sample, as at least that stands a chance of compiling error/warning-free. Were that the case, they should extricate all references to `NULL` from this question. Otherwise, it makes no sense at all with that array decl as-is.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have edited the question with how I store Null pointer in the array now

Comment: I agree that binary search is the wrong tool when the data isn't sorted (empty strings would all sort to the front). Imagine one string surrounded by thousands of empty strings; how can you reasonably find that string using a binary search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change compare code.  A `NULL` in `arr[mid]` is essentially a "skip" this element, so the compare needs to *linearly* seek to the next or preceding element.

To guard against worst case conditions really messing up the code, insure that a subsequent search of the two halves of the list do not re-scan a group of `NULL` elements about `mid`.  Watch out for `NULL` at either end of the list.

The worst case is `O(n*n)` which occurs with lots of `NULL`.  Otherwise `O(n*ln2(n))` performance can be expected if `NULL` is rare.

Further, no need for a recursive call.  See comments

```
int search(const char *arr[], const char *strtofind, int l, int r)
  while (l <= r) {
    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    int right_min = mid + 1;
    while (arr[mid] == NULL) {
      // If entire left side and mid are NULL ...
      if (mid == 0) {
        return search(arr, strtofind, right_min, r);
        // or { l = right_min; continue; }
      }
      mid--;
    }
    int cmp = strcmp(strtofind, arr[mid]);
    if (cmp == 0) {
      return mid;
    }
    if(val > 0) {
      return search(arr, strtofind, right_min, r);
      // or { l = right_min; continue; }
    }
    int left_max = mid - 1;
    return search(arr, strtofind, l, left_max);
    // or { r = left_max; }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Suggest: use `const`.

An efficient method exist if the `arr[]` with all `NULL` are at one end. `O(n*ln2(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will skip over the nulls. It resorts to a linear search once it hits nulls, but I can't think of a better way to do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int search(char arr[][20], char *strtofind, int l, int r)
{
    int mid , val, down = 1, start;
    if(l <= r)
    {
        mid = (l+r)/2;
        start = mid;
        while(0 == arr[mid])
        {
            if(down)
            {
                if(mid >= l)
                {
                    mid--;
                }
                else
                {
                    down = 0;
                    mid = start;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(mid <= r)
                {
                    mid++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        val = strcmp(strtofind, arr[mid]);
        if(val == 0)
            return mid;
        else if(val > 0)
        {
            return search(arr, strtofind,mid+1,r);
        }
        else
        {
            return search(arr, strtofind, l, mid-1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int idx;
    char arr[][20] = {"STR1", "STR2","STR3","STR4"};

    int num = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    idx = search(arr, "STR2", 0, num-1);
    if(-1 != idx)
    {
        printf("Found at = %d\n", idx);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not found");
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do strcmp(), check for NULL. If its NULL then go for that_index-1. It will work.